# Phreg coefficients

Tags: statistics, sas, survival-analysis

Are the parameter estimates given in SAS already exponentiated? I know that the Phreg model takes the form h(t) = e^(Bx+Bx(1)). However, I wasn't sure if SAS is giving the parameter values as e^B. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, as mentioned in SAS manual (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_a0000000708.htm)

> The OUTEST= data set contains one observation for each BY group containing the maximum likelihood estimates of the regression coefficients.

SAS outputs exp(B) as the hazards ratio (also known as risk ratio) for the explanatory variable with regression coefﬁcient B (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect030.htm).